# How to make powershell file search faster on an entire network

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to search all drives on all machines in an AD network and my methods are not very efficient. Basically, I came up with a script like this, here's what it does:

1. gets all computers from AD.
2. checks if there's WMI connectivity, logs the machine so I can take a look after.
3. gets all physical drives on the computer.
4. searches for the file on a remote share

---

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -filter *  | Select -Exp Name
$computers.Count
$i = 0
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
$i++ 
Write-Host "Checking Computer Number " $i " with the hostname " $computer
if (Test-Connection $computer -Quiet ) 
{
$drives = get-wmiobject -computer $computer win32_logicaldisk -filter "drivetype=3" | select -Exp DeviceID
foreach ($drive in $drives) 
{
$drive = $drive.Substring(0,$drive.Length-1) + "$"
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force \\$computer\$drive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Extension -eq ".crypt") } | Select-Object Name,Directory| Export-Csv C:\FoundFiles.csv -nti -append
}
}
else 
{
$computer >> C:\OfflineComputers.txt
}
}
```

The problem with this is that this is very inefficient and slow. It's probably going to take weeks to complete on a network of 150+ servers and 50+ clients.

How do you think I can make this run faster? Would sending a command to each server with "Invoke Command" work? I don't need the actual code to do it, just a direction would be enough.

Comment: Searching network drives does imply downloading their whole directory listing tree and then the search is done locally.  So running a command remotely would at least greatly reduce the network load, and possibly allow you to run the searches in parallel.

Comment: Actually, this is going much faster than I expected, Overnight, it was able to scan 40 servers and it should be completed within a few days (now that it's the weekend, I won't bother).

Comment: If you're ok with how slow it goes, please post an answer so you can mark it accepted. If you want to improve performance look into [PowerShell Workflows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134242(v=ws.11).aspx) and/or [`Start-Job`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849698.aspx). Both could be used to parallelize your example script.